# Custom CSS Font loads on PC, not on IOS

Tags: ios, css, fonts

I am trying to customize the font on my site title to Raleway in Wordpress.

I have added the google font code in `Customize` > `Typography`. This is working to change the font on my PC but not on my mobile device.

I added this code to the Custom CSS panel:

```
@site-title {
    font-family: 'Raleway';
    font-style: light;
    src: url ('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway');
}
```

Nothing seems to work. Any ideas of what I can do?

my site: [stillnorthretreatco.com](http://stillnorthretreatco.com)

Thanks!!

Comment: Provide a screenshot on your iOS device along with the version. It's working fine on iOS 11

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you put your link to the font one line below the style tag that references it. Switch those two lines:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you inadvertently put a space after "Raleway", so the URL is invalid:

`<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway " rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">`

Try removing the space so that it resolves properly.

Once I removed the space in Safari developer mode, the font appeared properly.